# Is it good practice to use the default event_loop of the main thread in an external python package?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am currently developing an external pip package, which can be used to send out specific data via websockets. I don't know if it can be harmful, to use the asyncio `event_loop` of the main thread or if I should run my own thread with my own `event_loop`.

One problem I see with the approach of using the `event_loop` of the main thread would be, that the user could perform blocking tasks and my code would never get executed. Is this a legitimate concern?

Edit: I want everything as simple as possible for the user of the package and therefore only expose a single sync function that can be used to send data.

Comment: Ideally you'd just expose your API as `async def` functions (and async context managers etc) and not care about which event loop it's running in. It is up to the user of an async API to deploy it in a functional event loop; that applies equally to asyncio itself as it does to libraries built on top of it such as aiohttp or websockets. Yours should be no exception.

Comment: I want everything as easy as possible and therefore only expose a single sync function. However, the websocket package I use, is built on top of asyncio